# How to create an array of arrays, from an array of objects using .map?

Tags: javascript

Given the following code:

```
var data = [];
for (let i = 0; i <2; i++) {
  data.push({
    "a": "1",
    "b": "2"
  });
}

console.log(data);

data.map((el) => {
  var row = Object.keys(el).map(key => el[key]);
  console.log(row);
  return row;
});

console.log(data);
```

Why does this not produce an array of arrays, like:

```
[
  ["1", "2"],
  ["1", "2"]
]
```

Here is a CodePen: http://codepen.io/24ma13wg/pen/MbbQZr

Comment: the map method doesn't mutate the array, it just returns a new array.
What you're missing is using the return value of map..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It does, nearly. You need to store the result of [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
var data = [], result;
for (let i = 0; i <2; i++) {
  data.push({
    "a": "1",
    "b": "2"
  });
}

result = data.map(el => Object.keys(el).map(key => el[key]));
// ^^^^^ missing assignment

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to update the array, you should do it manually:

```js
var data = [];
for (let i = 0; i <2; i++) {
  data.push({
    "a": 2*i,
    "b": 2*i+1
  });
}
console.log(data);
data.forEach((el,i,arr) => {
  arr[i] = Object.keys(el).map(key => el[key]);
});
console.log(data);
```

Also consider using ES2017's [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```js
data = data.map(Object.values);
```

Comment: do you have made the same experience, that in the evening are more downvoters around?

Comment: @NinaScholz Not sure. In the morning I don't answer. But I don't receive many downvotes in the evening neither